# Any alternatives for linkedtransfer queue with size restrictions in java 7/8?

Tags: java, apache-commons, java.util.concurrent

To implement producer/consumer pattern, I have used
[LinkedTransferQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedTransferQueue.html).

check the below code

```
while (true) {

    String tmp = new randomString();
    if (linkedTransferQueueString.size() < 10000) {
        linkedTransferQueueString.add(tmp);             
        }

}
```

From the docs, it states the size is O(n) operation :(. So for adding an element, it should go through the whole collection.

Is there any other concurrent collection queue which has size restriction?
Could not find any in [java standard collections](http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-collections/concurrent-collection-cheatsheet/), [apache concurrent collections](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/package-summary.html) ?

Comment: What's the issue with `BlockingQueue`?

Comment: I do not know why i missed blockingQueue,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`BlockingQueue` is

> [BlockingQueue implementations are thread-safe](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html)
>
> [...]
>
> A BlockingQueue may be capacity bounded.

and an `ArrayBlockingQueue` is

> [A bounded blocking queue backed by an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html)

Here's how you would write your example with it:

```
BlockingQueue queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10000);
while (true) {
    String tmp = new randomString();
    if (!queue.offer(tmp)) {
        // the limit was reached, item was not added
    }
}
```

Or for a simple producer/consumer example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // using a low limit so it doesn't take too long for the queue to fill
    BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(10);

    Runnable producer = () -> {
        if (!queue.offer(randomString())) {
            System.out.println("queue was full!");
        }
    };
    Runnable consumer = () -> {
        try {
            queue.take();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    };
    ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(4);
    // produce faster than consume so the queue becomes full eventually
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(producer, 0, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(consumer, 0, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `ArrayBlockingQueue`?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ArrayBlockingQueue.html

It has size restriction and concurrency.

Also, the size is O(1).

```
public int size() {
    final ReentrantLock lock = this.lock;
    lock.lock();
    try {
        return count;
    } finally {
        lock.unlock();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you please go through `BlockingQueue`.
Here is the best link I found on the internet - [BlockingQueue](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/blockingqueue.html).  `BlockingQueue` is an interface, it is in the package - ***java.util.concurrent*** and it has multiple implementations:-

1. `ArrayBlockingQueue`
2. `DelayQueue`
3. `LinkedBlockingQueue`
4. `PriorityBlockingQueue`
5. `SynchronousQueue`

Answer (score 1):

@OP: You had already accepted the answer and it is correct as well, but you still raise the bounty, so I am assuming you are more looking for the concept so I will just throw light on that part.

Now, your issue is that you are not happy with `O(n)` for size operation so it means your solution is either:

- the data structure should be able to tell you that queue is full.
- size operation should return you result in constant time.

It is not common that size operation will give `O(n)` but since in case of `LinkedTransferQueue` there is async behavior, so complete queue is traversed to ensure the number of elements in the queue. Otherwise most of the queue implementations give you size result in constant time, but you really don't need to do this size check, please keep on reading.

If you have hard dependency on purpose of `LinkedTransferQueue` i.e. you want to dequeue based on how long an element has been on the queue for some producer, then I don't think there is any alternative except that you can do some dirty thing like extending `LinkedTransferQueue` and then tracking the number of elements yourself, but soon it can become a mess and cannot give you accurate result and may give approximate result.

If you do not have any hard dependency on `LinkedTransferQueue` then you can use some flavor of `BlockingQueue` and many of them enable you to have a **"bounded"** queue (bounded queue is what you need) in some way or other - for example, `ArrayBlockingQueue` is implicitly bounded and you can create a bounded `LinkedBlockingQueue` like this `new  LinkedBlockingQueue(100)`. You can check the documentation for other queues.

And then you can use `offer` method of the queue, which will return FALSE if the queue is full, so if you are getting FALSE then you can handle as you want, so like this you need not to do explicit size check, you can simply put the element in the queue using `offer` method and it will return you a boolean indicating whether element was successfully placed in the queue or not.